# как сделать в либе ANTLR4 пространство имён для описания грамматики javascript доступной?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, ecmascript, antlr

Постараюсь объяснить по подробнее. У меня дипломная работа и мне нужно представить программу на C# , одна из задач у которой это обрабатывать лексические элементы javascript кода. Я использую visual studio 2013. Для начала я установил ALTNR4 на винду , следуя по всем шагам , что написано на официальном сайте www.antlr.org. ОК. Дальше для реализации этой либы в проекте C# , я установил в него такую либу dll соответственно , которая прилагалась в папке с различными runtime-ами : C:...\antlr4-4.5.3\runtime\CSharp\antlr-csharp-runtime-4.5.3\Antlr4.Runtime.dll . Однако я не нашёл ни одного класса в Antlr4.Runtime.dll , которая связана с синтаксическим разбором javascript кода и построением деревьев Ast на основе концепции javascript(должен быть просто приложен класс похожий на JavascriptLexer для начала , но опять же я его не нашёл). Однако я слышал , что для antlr есть специальный файл-скрипт JavaScript.g описания грамматики кода javascript(ECMAScript). Но как мне использовать ECMAScript для моей либы Antlr4 в проекте C# в visual studio , чтобы из него достать namespace , отвечающие за описания синтаксиса исходного кода javascript (с классом JavascriptLexer и тому подобное) и использовать для создания ast дерева из моего исходного кода javascript и пройтись соответственно по всем его нодам ? А то про использование файла грамматики ECMAScript в C# для Visual Studio чтото не нахожу ничего толкового

Comment: Сорри. Оказывается я ошибся. antlr не поддерживает язык C# так как эта либа написана на все 87% на java.